# Select different columns in each row of R based on input, and count values bigger than 0 in each row

Tags: r, apply, mapply

I have a data frame look like this

`val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 val6 diff
  4   0    0    2     3   0     3
  0   1    1    0     2   0     4`

For each row, i want to start counting by column 1 + diff, and get the count of values bigger than 0. So the results for row 1 will be count value bigger than 0 starting from column 3, which is 2. Result for row 2 would be count for value bigger than 0 start from column 4, which is 1.

What would be the best way to address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option where we `replace` the values based on the 'diff' column to `NA` and get the `rowSums` where the values are greater than 0

```
rowSums(replace(df1[-ncol(df1)], col(df1[-ncol(df1)])
          <= df1$diff, NA) > 0, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 2 1
```

---

Or another option is `apply`

```
apply(df1, 1, function(x)  sum(seq_along(x) >  x['diff'] & x > 0)-1)
#[1] 2 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(val1 = c(4L, 0L), val2 = 0:1, val3 = 0:1, val4 = c(2L, 
0L), val5 = 3:2, val6 = c(0L, 0L), diff = 3:4), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thank you akrun! But when i run the results for both options i got different results..

Comment: @jingcc With the data example showed, I get the same results

Comment: i think i know why, my data set included other columns than the listed values, it also contains column for ID. After i filter out to only the columns selected it's fine. Thanks!